# I have existing Login Application Created in JSP without MVC and I want to convert it into Angularjs SPA

Tags: java, angularjs, jsp

I have Two Textboxes username and Password Which are currently present in JSP and Now I want to convert it into AngularJS SPA Program.
The Login form or the Index page Consists of Username, Password, In-Time, out-Time and Reset.
The Form calls the Java program to store this values or verify the credentials.
I am stuck how to use routing in this existing application. Any Help would be Appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help if you could expand on your question.

However I am taking few assumptions 
1. You have an existing JSP application which you want to convert to Angular SPA
2. Your JSP application has a login page which has two textboxes namely UserId & Password and some additional controls.

You are looking at way of how do you still do your authentication with similar setup in Angular SPA, where in your earlier case it was simple Form Post and redirection on successful login.

The simple answer to your question would be create a in memory form(html) using jquery or javascript and do a post action which would return the form body on successful login. Assuming you get a token, store it on client side and authenticate the same on every subsequent request.

However this approach will not help you understand either SPA or Angular.

Here is my advise : First Understand SPA and the respective life cycle of SPA(Angular in particular). This will help you in devising a proper plan to migrate your current JSP application to Angular.
https://www.codeschool.com/beginners-guide-to-web-development/single-page-applications

I will be happy to help if you need any further guidance.

Comment: There are total three buttons In-Time out-Time and Reset
Two Textboxes One username and Password
when User clicks on In Time username and Password with System Time is stored in the database and vice versa for out Time